# Create a network of blogs with WordPress 3

Tags: multisite

I want to create a network of sites on the WordPress platform. [Apartment Therapy](http://www.apartmenttherapy.com/) is a prime example of how I would like to implement the network. They are using unique domains, not subdomains or directories.

Click Technology in the top nav for Unplggd, click Children for Ohdeedoh, etc.

Can you give me your opinion of how to best do this with WordPress 3.0.x multisite?

I've read some posts about WordPress multisite that give me a hint but I want to build the architecture right the first time.

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 4):

For setting up a network of sites **on different domains** use:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/
Otto has a great tutorial on the subject:
http://ottopress.com/2010/wordpress-3-0-multisite-domain-mapping-tutorial/

Andrea's ebook and Otto's tut helped me a lot with my first setup!

Answer (score 3):

Official instructions:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

Free ebook with screenshots:
http://wpebooks.com/2010/09/how-to-enable-multisite-in-wordpress/